# Error while installing keras in conda using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, deep-learning, keras, anaconda

Can anyone help here.
I am trying to install keras in conda using pip and I get below error:

> (C:\Users\HARSHALL\Anaconda3) C:\Users\HARSHALL>pip install --upgrade keras
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\HARSHALL\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in 
>   from pip import main
>   File "C:\Users\HARSHALL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_init_.py", line 28, in 
>   from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar # noqa
>   File "C:\Users\HARSHALL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\mercurial.py", line 9, in 
>   from pip.download import path_to_url
>   File "C:\Users\HARSHALL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 41, in 
>   from pip._vendor.requests.adapters import BaseAdapter, HTTPAdapter
>   ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests.adapters'

Comment: did you try: conda install keras?

Comment: Yes that does not work as well.

Comment: please update the error message for conda install keras

Comment: I ran the following command in the conda prompt and it worked:          
         conda install -c conda-forge keras tensorflow